# UWP create Adaptive and Advanced Tile

Tags: c#, uwp

I programming for UWP (Universal Windows Platform) with C# language.  I complete my app and I want to create a tile for that. I read about adaptive tile and way of create them. I read all pages about tile but I don't know how to create a tile like this app in the store. I want a chart in my tile and I don't know how to create it? (Name of app is Network Data)

[image: Network Data]

I don't know but the chart in that tile is a picture? if It is, How can't I create chart Image for my app. I can't create 100 more image for different shape of chart for my tile!!
Is it possible to help me?
 I'm sorry for Bad English. Thanks.

Comment: I've never used it but a few days ago I read about [`XamlRenderingBackgroundTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask) that someone is using to generate image from some XAML code and then he's using the generated image on a tile.

Comment: Thanks. I search for this but I take away from it. There is no sample for it. only one sample for windows 8 in C++ language. someone translated code to C# but it doesn't work and I have visual studio 2017 so I can't check windows 8 app. No one make an app for windows 10 to see it works or not. so If you can, can you give a simple example file in UWP or someone that do that. if you can't no problem However thanks for answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to use it. I read about it [here](http://www.hannesbiribauer.com/wordpress/?p=1144) so maybe you could try asking him how does it work.

Comment: Thanks But I prefer to use simple tile because difficulty of that.

Comment: @AminBorjian You don't have to create 100 more images for the different shapes etc. `VS2019` would create all those images with different shapes for you. This [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#generating-all-assets-at-once) explains how to do it. All you need to do is add you one image in the `Source` field of `Package.appxmanifest` file and click on `Generate` button to generate all the images with different shapes.